# Simulate javascript keypress on applet element

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, applet

I would like to simulate a keypress on an applet element, not an input form. Is it possible to make it look like the actual key has been pressed or not?

I tried a lot of different code, so if anyone knows if It's possible, thanks in advance.

```
  var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
  e.which = 77; // # Some key code value
  $("applet").trigger(e);
```

I was using jQuery which is not a problem to me. Sadly, it isn't that simple.

Comment: If it's a java applet running in JVM, triggering a regular event probably won't work.

Comment: checkout this if the example helps: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingJavaScriptFromApplet.html

Comment: Thanks, but I do not have access to change the actual applet, just the javascript, so I only want to "emulate" a keypress (of a specific key like {space}).

Comment: Do you have an URL where we can visit the applet?  This might be possible using a bit of hacking, but it would be necessary to have direct access to it, to experiment.